# Wrong order with SharePoint updates

Tags: wss, hotfix

I have installed a hotfix package for SharePoint and after that I found out that there was another for WSS.

I understand that, as long that we have separate hotfixes for WSS and SharePoint, if for solving one problem, there aren't both SharePoint and WSS hotfixes (I mean, that one component is only affected by the WSS one), I can normally apply the WSS hotfix package after having applied the SharePoint one.

Is that true?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a prerequisite to install MOSS updates before WSS updates (read the KB article concerned to make sure). However it is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would not trust to that. Better to run any WSS patches/hotfixes before the SharePoint ones.